# Can leaflet read OSM xml format?

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, format, overpass-api

I want something similar to `OpenLayers.Format.OSM` for leaflet. i know how to use a geojson file and i have found support for GPX and WFS in plugins, but not for OSM.

Simply saying i want to make [this map](http://overpass-api.de/open_layers_bbox.html) using leaflet and overpass.

Comment: .OSM XML is not supported in leaflet. You could use openlayers to convert to GeoJSON. But then you could use Openlayers for maps as well of course.

Comment: Thanks @warrieka. I have already done it in openlayers and i want to do the same in leaflet. if you are sure, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Leaflet plugin that can render OSM XML: https://github.com/jfirebaugh/leaflet-osm It's used by the openstreetmap.org site to display a data layer for browsing and editing.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. Leaflet can read geojson so try converting osm to geojson using [this](https://github.com/jillesvangurp/osm2geojson) Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

To load OSM data through **Overpass API** in Leaflet layer using this plugin:

http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-layerjson/examples/overpass.html

Comment: This is good for smallish datasets and/or scenarios where you won't be querying a lot.  But if you want to, say, show everything in a country, on a website that will be regularly visited, you might get your ip blocked.